# Prove that the following problem is undecidable by a reduction from the halting problem:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computability, automata, turing-machines, decidability

Prove that the following problem is undecidable by a reduction from the halting problem:

“Does a given Turing Machine M accept any string of form a^2k for k ≥ 1?”

I'm having trouble understanding the intuition behind the Halting problem reduction, could someone please explain in an intuitive and easy to understand why this is the case? I've watched some videos and studied some material online but a, having a hard time with this concept.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).